# Summing columns for each value in a different table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given tables A and B as shown below:

```
Table A       Table B
┌────┬───┐    ┌────┬─────┬───────┐
│ id │ c │    │ id │ Aid │ value │
┝━━━━┿━━━┥    ┝━━━━┿━━━━━┿━━━━━━━┥
│  1 │ 1 │    │  1 │  1  │    50 │
├────┼───┤    ├────┼─────┼───────┤
│  2 │ 0 │    │  2 │  1  │    20 │
├────┼───┤    ├────┼─────┼───────┤
│  3 │ 1 │    │  3 │  2  │    75 │
└────┴───┘    ├────┼─────┼───────┤
              │  4 │  3  │    23 │
              ├────┼─────┼───────┤
              │  5 │  3  │    17 │
              └────┴─────┴───────┘
```

How does one get the sum of the column `B.value` for each value of `A.id` that meets the condition `c=1`?

That is, the following:

```
┌────┬───────┐
│ id │ value │
┝━━━━┿━━━━━━━┥
│  1 │    70 │
├────┼───────┤
│  3 │    40 │
└────┴───────┘
```

I've tried doing

```sql
SELECT A.id as id, SUM(B.value) as value
  FROM A INNER JOIN B ON B.Aid = A.id
  WHERE c = 1
```

but that just returns the following:

```
┌────┬───────┐
│ id │ value │
┝━━━━┿━━━━━━━┥
│  3 │   110 │
└────┴───────┘
```

Comment: You forgot `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a `group by`:

```
SELECT A.id as id, SUM(B.value) as value
FROM A INNER JOIN
     B
     on B.Aid = A.id
WHERE c = 1
GROUP BY A.id;
```